# Cordinator Layout scrolling not working when fragment has view other than RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

I've two **fragments** in the **ViewPager** in my **Activity**,

One has a **RecyclerView**

```
<com.fourbigbrothers.boilerplate.widgets.recyclerview.FbbRecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rvMyWorks"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

another one have a **LinearLayout** & **RecyclerView** inside a **FrameLayout**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

  <LinearLayout
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_card_material_normal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvHashtagsToFilter"
            tools:text="#cr7,#kb9,#halamadrid"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.fourbigbrothers.boilerplate.widgets.recyclerview.FbbRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvTrendingWorks"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</FrameLayout>
```

The **scrolling behavior** is working fine in the **first** fragment, but not in the **second** fragment. I've tried using a **NestedScrollView** instead of **FrameLayout**, but found no luck.
Please Help.

Comment: I have exactly same requirement and it works fine with nestedcrollview. 

View pager has
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

Fragment which has Relativelayout is wrapped inside NestedSCrollView.